# Transparent material in Blender in render mode (Eevee or Cycles) in Python, Blender 2.93

Tags: python, mesh, transparency

I've managed to create a transparent object in viewport mode, but not in render mode:

```py
# verts, edges, faces = ...

mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('bboxmesh')
mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
bbox = bpy.data.objects.new("bbox", mesh)
material = bpy.data.materials.new("mymaterial")
material.diffuse_color = (1.0,0.0,1.0, 0.05)
material.blend_method = 'BLEND'
mesh.materials.append(material)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(bbox)
```

Basically, I compute optimal oriented 3D bounding box with Open3D and would like to display it a transparent cuboid.

I could not find how to easily render the wireframe (in render mode), so looking either for rendering the wireframe or having a transparent material :)

I found some tutorials for doing it in UI, but not in Python. I've been using Blender for just one week, so I'd like to avoid configuring Nodes pipelines if the same can be achieved without.

Thank you!

Comment: Personally, doing this instead of just using nodes, even nodes set up with python, seams going over a mountain to avoid a mole hill. Nodes are fairly easy to set up in python.

Comment: I don't have skills for now to convert a visual tutorial setting up Nodes into Python code :/ I'm sure I'll learn it with more experience. But even from tinkering for a week, it seems that many simple tasks are super-hard to do without falling back to Nodes :(

Comment: really, it’s not that hard. Especially if you just want to render a semi transparent cuboid. I can almost put the necessary code in a comment, but I don’t remember it just well enough. I’ll have to go look at a previous time I did this.

Comment: I think I found a snippet for configuring render-time material properties: `material.use_nodes = True;  material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[19].default_value = 0.05`

Comment: Is there a way to do without constant `19`? Is there a way to specify it once and having it both for viewport and render mode? How do I set color for the render mode?

Comment: 1) yes, you can index the input by its name. node.inputs[“Alpha”] 2) Yes, in fact I think it would be very hard not to do this.

Comment: One more question: how to keep only wireframe / display edges only in rendering mode...

Comment: It depends somewhat on what render engine you’re using. A reliable method would be to use some system of grease pencil (possibly with the lineart GP modifier), or the mesh wire frame modifier which makes 3D geometry along previous edges. But to actually display just thin 1-pixel lines as they mathematically exist, you will have to use EEVEE specific settings, if it is possible at all.

Comment: I don't mind edges being thicker than 1px. So if you know a way of doing that programmatically, I would be greatful :)

Comment: Could I manually add thin cylinders to display the cuboid's wireframe? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add

Comment: Probably. How easy it is depends on what variation there is in the cuboid. I would just use the wireframe modifierZ

Comment: Wireframe modifier would display in render mode?  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html

Comment: Okay, it seems that the wireframe modifier works for me. How could I configure it from Python? It also seems that the wireframe modifier does not work for meshes consisting of only edges (without any faces)

Comment: I had not thought of that, and it is true. You maybe should switch to grease pencil

Comment: I managed to script grease pencil in viewport mode, I can see the cuboid edges. But they do not appear in render mode. Would you have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: Setting `gp_stroke.line_width = 1000` seems to help, but this is weird. Also, can't set stroke color from Python :(

Comment: I wish I knew how to switch to discussions. Anyway, I’m not sure what to tell you here. What version of blender are you using?

Comment: It's 2.93. I somehow made it work with `line_width = 1000`, but still not sure why it's limited to 1000 and what units it uses. Some sample output: https://github.com/facebookresearch/meshrcnn/issues/100 and my full code: https://gist.github.com/vadimkantorov/eb53ce740cb80c12444079875facff85. If you have any comments on this Blender code, please tell me :) It's a nasty pastiche of copy-pastes from various places. I don't understand internal Blender structures well for now.

Comment: Sigh :/ Grease Pencil does not work on headless setups :( https://gist.github.com/zocker-160/0688a4902421158b66f52dff3966058a#gistcomment-3743669

Comment: I wonder then if some way to render just edges exists for headless rendering :)

Comment: that wasn’t what the original question said. I think you should close this question and open a new one. The comment section is getting huge with new information and discoveries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @TheLabCat I found a solution using Nodes:

```py
material.use_nodes = True
material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs['Alpha'].default_value = 0.05
material.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs['Base Color'].default_value = (1, 0, 0, 0.05) # red color
```